# In-lane, cross 64-bit element data movement in AVX2

Tags: x86, intel, simd, micro-optimization, avx2

Are there any register-to-register<sup>1</sup> AVX or AVX2 instructions which move data in any way *between* 64-bit halves of 128-bit lanes in `ymm` regs, that don't use port 5 on contemporary Intel<sup>2</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Such a thing *kind of* exists for memory sources, in the form of the `D` and `Q` broadcast instructions.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Haswell through Skylake-S (although if anything exists in AVX-512 as implemented in SKX it's worth mentioning).</sub>

Comment: I assume you're excluding Ice Lake (2nd shuffle unit that can run some shuffles), or pre-Haswell where integer shuffles had 2/clock throughput.  With 1/c shuffle throughput, store + broadcast reload is at least worth *considering*.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes I was intending to limit it to AVX2-supporting CPUs currently available, basically Haswell through Skylake and variants. Clarified with a footnote. I actually was thinking of pre-AVX-512 but if there's an answer in pre-ICL AVX-512 I'm also interested.

Comment: Heh, was about to comment that Zen 2 probably has 0.5c throughput for `vpshufd ymm` (couldn't find an InstLatx64 or other source for that, though.  But Zen 1 does have 128-bit shuffle units on 2 ports).  Anyway, you did tag Intel and just made that extra clear with an edit.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's [here](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0870F10_K17_Matisse_InstLatX64.txt) and yeah it has 0.5 inv tput. It's not all roses though, Zen2 has terrible performance for some shuffles, e.g., the important `vpermd` at 8/2 lat/tput (!!). In general the shuffle performance for Zen/Zen2 is hard to memorize, it doesn't follow simple rules like Intel (almost always 1/1 or 3/1, in or cross lane).

Comment: Does `PHMINPOSUW` count?

Comment: Yeah, Zen1 was pretty arbitrary for how many uops lane-crossing shuffles took.  I had hoped Zen2 would be more like Intel when they widened the shuffle ALUs to 256-bit, but maybe they didn't actually do that.  So it's a bit like Merom which only had a 64-bit shuffle unit making `pshufd` slow but `pshuflw` or `shufpd` fast.  (Probably Zen2's shuffle ports each have 2x in-lane shuffle units.  So in-lane shuffles are full speed, but lane crossing needs extra uops for granularity < 128-bit).  Broadcasts are still fast-ish (4c latency), and `vperm2f128` is fine (3c latency).

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah and some lane crossing stuff is 1 cycle lat even, like `VPERM2I128`. Since `shufd` is fast, you can do many less-than-general-but-interesting types of lane crossing shuffles at high speed (2c latency even - at least assuming the latencies hold when mixing ops, rather than the back-to-back-same-op tests from instlat). Zen will suffer however because binaries will be compiled with settings that favor Intel, so they'll see mostly downside from the negative deviations and little upside from the positive ones.

Comment: @harold - I'm going to disallow it because I was looking for `ymm`-using AVX instructions. I didn't mention the `ymm` part, so I guess _technically_ it does it, but it has no `ymm` version and is only in AVX due to the default VEX-encoding pretty much everything got. I just edited the ?n to make `ymm` explicit.

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think it's possible in 1 reg-reg instruction, but store/reload can move data in-lane without port 5**.  Even funky stuff like `dppd` or `vcvtps2pd` need a port 5 shuffle.  All register-source shuffle instructions run on port 5 in Haswell and later (until Ice Lake adds a 2nd shuffle unit on another port that can do some shuffles).

Obviously a misaligned reload can do any byte-shift but that will cause a store-forwarding stall, and you'd have to mask off unwanted data.

**[`vmovddup x/y/zmm, [mem]`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movddup) runs purely on load ports, exactly like `vbroadcastsd`.**  It's an in-lane broadcast of the low qword.  `vmovsldup` and [`vmovshdup`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movshdup) also only need a load port, but don't meet your requirement of moving *between* 64-bit halves of a lane.

There's no `movhdup` that duplicates the *high* half within each lane, only `movddup` that duplicates the low double-precision FP element.  SSE3 for xmm, AVX1 for the ymm version.

---

As @harold points out, [`phminposuw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/phminposuw) can put data from the high 64 bits into the low 64 bits.  But it's not available in a YMM version.  It may be the only instruction that has a special-purpose execution unit that can do that outside of shuffles.  `psadbw` works inside 64-bit elements.  `vdbpsadbw` is 1 uop for p5 on SKX.  `mpsadbw` is multi-uop including 2p5.  `phadd` instructions are also 2p5.

---

**Zen 2 has 0.5c throughput for `vpshufd ymm`** ([instlat](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0870F10_K17_Matisse_InstLatX64.txt)).  It's slower than Intel at handling lane-crossing shuffles with granularity less than 128-bit, but good performance on in-lane shuffles and 128-bit shuffles like `vperm2f128`.